# Why notifyItemRemoved works slowly?

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, swipe-gesture

I have implemented swipe and delete feature in my RecyclerView. But the problem is that when I delete item, the previous item rise up, and below this item I see the same item a few sec, but after deleting only one item visible(previous)  Also I tried to use adapter.notifyDataSetChanged() but when I have swiped the item, I can see this item a few seconds in the previous position, and after less than 1 sec item is deleting.

So, for example I have list

1. List item1
2. List item2

After swipe and call notifyItemRemoved() and I see such list 1 sec

1. List item2
2. List item2

And finaly

1. List item2

Here the code

```
    ItemTouchHelper swipeToDismissTouchHelper = new ItemTouchHelper(new ItemTouchHelper.SimpleCallback(
            ItemTouchHelper.LEFT | ItemTouchHelper.RIGHT, ItemTouchHelper.LEFT | ItemTouchHelper.RIGHT) {
        @Override
        public boolean onMove(RecyclerView recyclerView, RecyclerView.ViewHolder viewHolder, RecyclerView.ViewHolder target) {
            // callback for drag-n-drop, false to skip this feature
            return false;
        }

        @Override
        public void onSwiped(RecyclerView.ViewHolder viewHolder, int direction) {
            // callback for swipe to dismiss, removing item from data and adapter
            int itemPosition = viewHolder.getAdapterPosition();
            Log.v("Position", Integer.toString(itemPosition));
            adapter_.removeItem(itemPosition);
        }
    });
    swipeToDismissTouchHelper.attachToRecyclerView(chatsRecyclerView_);
```

And here method in my adapter

```
public void removeItem(int position){
    Cursor cursor = getCursor();
    if (cursor.getCount() != 0) {
        Log.v("Size", Integer.toString(cursor.getCount()));
        cursor.moveToPosition(position);
        String chatIdOnServer = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(MegaFleetDatabaseOpenHelper.ChatsTable.ID_ON_SERVER));
        context_.startService(ChatsInfoUpdateService.createLeaveChatIntent(this.context_, chatIdOnServer));
        ChatsTableHelper.deleteChat(this.context_, chatIdOnServer);
       // this.notifyDataSetChanged();
       this.notifyItemRemoved(position);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The solution is to call swapCursor() after removing of item. In such case everything works fine.

```
 @Override
        public void onSwiped(RecyclerView.ViewHolder viewHolder, int direction) {
            // callback for swipe to dismiss, removing item from data and adapter
            int itemPosition = viewHolder.getAdapterPosition();
            Log.v("Position", Integer.toString(itemPosition));
            adapter_.removeItem(itemPosition);
            adapter_.swapCursor(ChatsTableHelper.getAllChatsInfo(ChatListActivity.this));
        }
    });
```